# How to create a link to open a Tab within your site

Tags: hyperlink, tabs

http://www.duellinksmeta.com/pve2.html

This is a test page of my site. I learned how to create a link to jump to a specific part of a page, but what I want to accomplish is a link that opens a tab and/or jumps to content within a tab.

My main reason for this is I want people to be able to share a link that when used as a URL, it will go directly to the relevant tab opened with the content they want to see.

Comment: What have you tried? Please pose some code. Also, you can try using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Without using javascript and CSS there is no provision in HTML to accomplish what you are looking for. However, if you do use javascript and CSS, this is quite easy. Tab sets can be implemented with <ul> and <li> elements, and jumps to tabs and specific bookmarks on tabs can be implemented with javascript based manipulation of CSS rules.

Comment: My site is made with weebly.com. Is there a way to add javascript and CSS tabs similar to what I have right now on http://www.duellinksmeta.com/pve2.html ?